# how can we pass bearer token created in xml into 2 nd api which is placed in another thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

how can we pass bearer token created in xml into 2 nd api which is placed in another thread group in jmeter I have tried with set property but it is not working as the body of token is in xml.

Answer (score 0):

If your token comes in the XML response just extract it using [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or better [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations).

Once you have the token stored as JMeter Variable there will be 2 options:

1. Convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
2. Or use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) (see [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan for reference usage)